# read only certain contents from a file

Tags: python, file-io

I have a file loaded with words and let's say, I only want to read the ones that start with an 'M' (e.g.) to be memory efficient, can I do this or do I need to read the complete file and filter afterwards?

Thanks

Comment: You can't know if a word starts with an M until you read it, so yes, you'll need to read the whole file.  (If it's broken up into lines, you can read it line by line and throw away what you don't need from each line so you don't need too much memory.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your file is a list of newline seperated words you can do

```
words_starting_in_M = []
with open(filepath) as wordsfile:
    for line in wordsfile:
        if line.startswith("M"):
            words_starting_in_M.append(line.rstrip())
```

Although you have to *read* the whole file, you avoid holding it all in memory, so you get your memory efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the entire file since it is the only way to parse the word and find out whether it has an M or not.

You can do what you want with:

```
words_starting_in_M = []
with open(filepath) as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        for word in line.split():
            if word.startswith("M"):
                words_starting_in_M.append(word.rstrip())
```

This code read a line (assuming no words are split on two or more lines). Then it splits each line by spaces, and then adds to words_starting_in_M those words that start with M.

Answer (score 0):

On the flip side of this coin, if you plan on using multiple times on the same file you can store in a dictionary to make lookup in constant time (memory efficiency is O(n) though):

```
from collections import defaultdict

word_lists = defaultdict(list)

with open(filepath) as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        for word in line.split():
            word_lists[word[0].lower()].append(word)
```